# Are contextually related verbs, adjectives, and nouns antecedents of each other when used successively?

Tags: antecedents

> I must not **fear**. **Fear** is the mind-killer. **Fear** is the little-death that brings total obliteration.

Above is a quote from author Frank Herbert's Dune. It is arguably the most famous quote from his sci-fi series, so I feel it is a good representation of what I'm about to discuss.

In the first sentence, we can see that Herbert has used the plain verb 'fear.' The second sentence begins with the noun 'Fear,' which is repeated in the sentence that follows.

We can see similar examples with adjectives (this is my own example, not Herbert's):

> He was **afraid**. **Fear** was a common part of his life.

My question is this: is the verb 'fear' in Herbert's quotation the antecedent of the noun 'fear'? They are not in the same word category, but they are related terms. Or is this a simple case of a completely separate sentence that builds upon the context of the one preceding it? We know that fearing something means that the subject is experiencing 'fear,' so there may not be any strict grammatical link at all.

If we refer to the [Wikipedia article on antecedents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antecedent_(grammar)), I can't see an example similar to this.

Comment: The latter, I'd say.

Comment: Don't antecedents acquire pronouns?

Comment: @YosefBaskin Not always if we're to take the examples on Wikipedia at face value. 'Larry was helpful, and so was Kim.' Apparently, 'helpful' is the antecedent of 'so.'

Comment: A word that is a verb (to fear) and a noun (fear) does not require an antecedent. I don't even know what that would mean.

Comment: "Larry was helpful, and so was Kim" uses *so* as a pronoun.

Comment: The second sentence is talking about fear in general. It's related to the first sentence because they're both about being afraid, but it's not referring specifically to the character's fear.

Comment: You mention that Wikipedia's article on antecedents doesn't include examples like this. So doesn't that settle the question? Wikipedia's definition pretty clearly excludes the sorts of examples you're describing.

Comment: @alphabet Wikipedia does give examples of adverb phrases, such as 'very carefully,' being antecedents, so I guess that's where my curiosity was raised. 'Our helpers did it very carefully, and we did it like that as well.' They also highlight entire verb phrases as proforms (e.g., 'do the same'), so unless we're supposed to interpret 'the same' as the whole proform, in which case I'm not sure why the 'do' is in bold, I guess that expands the range of possibilities. It seems to imply that phrases within the same function (e.g., subject complement) can be antecedents and proforms.

Comment: Here is a link to an article about pro-forms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-form. This says that they take on many forms, not just nouns. From the comments, it seems unlikely that 'fear' (noun) takes 'fear' (verb) as antecedent, but given their close relation, I wondered if there might be a grammatical rule to directly connect them.

Comment: @MJAda Pro-forms are a specific set of words, e.g. the "that" in "we did it like that as well." "Fear" isn't one.

Comment: @alphabet What's your opinion on 'do' as a pro-form? While I follow the logic of that Wikipedia page, I'm aware that it's not the most reliable source.